# what is bf = @(p, varargin) b*exp((p-opt.pRef)*c); what does the @(p, varargin) do?

Tags: matlab

May I ask what the meaning of is `bf = @(p, varargin) b*exp((p-opt.pRef)*c);`  what does the `@(p, varargin)` do?
Thank you

Comment: It make an "anonymous function", i.e. now `bf` is a function that you can call as `bf(value, ....)`

Comment: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html